# how to add edit button in every row of table to edit respective row content

Tags: javascript, django

I'm working in Django. I print the table by using the for-loop in HTML page. here I have a Django form which should popup when press edit and update the database by the new value

```py
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            #
        </th>
        <th>
            Application Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Category
        </th>
        <th>
            Update
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for item in data %}

    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ forloop.counter }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{  item.0 }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{  item.1}}
        </td>


        <td>
            <button>Edit</button>

            edit
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}


    </tbody>
</table>

<form method="post" action='manageapp'>
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

I also need to have prefilled respective entry of the particular row

Comment: are you looking for an edit view?

Comment: Every item / row in the loop should have something unique, like an id, so that you know which row should be edited. You could put that value in the button like so `<button value="{{ item.id }}">Edit</button>`. The id value could also be the `{{ forloop.counter }}` value of the loop. You can start from there.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Right!